# Wait for Promise to be fulfilled (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, api, oauth-2.0, promise

How does one pause his Javascript function until a Promise (in this case of the OAuth2) has been fullfilled, so that I can get the redirect URL that it should be returning?

Using regular JS in a Firefox Webextension, running latest Firefox Developer (54.0a2)

```
function fetchOAuth2()
{
    var redirectURL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL() + "page.html";
    console.log(redirectURL);
    var clientID = "CLIENT ID";  
    var authURL = "https://trakt.tv/oauth/authorize";  // API I'm using
    authURL += `?response_type=code`;
    authURL += `&client_id=${clientID}`;
    authURL += `&redirect_uri=${redirectURL}`;
    console.log(authURL);
    var authorizationCode = browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        interactive: true,
        url: authURL
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches that are valid, so pick the one you prefer/fits with your code best.

**Use promise.then()**

```
function fetchOAuth2()
{
    var redirectURL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL() + "page.html";
    console.log(redirectURL);
    var clientID = "CLIENT ID";  
    var authURL = "https://trakt.tv/oauth/authorize";  // API I'm using
    authURL += `?response_type=code`;
    authURL += `&client_id=${clientID}`;
    authURL += `&redirect_uri=${redirectURL}`;
    console.log(authURL);

    browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        interactive: true,
        url: authURL
    })
    .then(function(authResult) {
        // do something with authResult
    })
}
```

If you want to access the authResult outside of this function then you will need to return the promise, and `then` it from the call site, i.e.

```
function fetchOAuth2()
{
    var redirectURL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL() + "page.html";
    console.log(redirectURL);
    var clientID = "CLIENT ID";  
    var authURL = "https://trakt.tv/oauth/authorize";  // API I'm using
    authURL += `?response_type=code`;
    authURL += `&client_id=${clientID}`;
    authURL += `&redirect_uri=${redirectURL}`;
    console.log(authURL);

    return browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        interactive: true,
        url: authURL
    })
}

fetchOAuth2().then(function(authResult) {
    // do something with auth result
});
```

**Use ES7 async/await**

This is a relatively new language feature, but it is supported in FF54.  If you need to support other browsers you would have to use Babel to allow compatibility.

```
async function fetchOAuth2()
{
    var redirectURL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL() + "page.html";
    console.log(redirectURL);
    var clientID = "CLIENT ID";  
    var authURL = "https://trakt.tv/oauth/authorize";  // API I'm using
    authURL += `?response_type=code`;
    authURL += `&client_id=${clientID}`;
    authURL += `&redirect_uri=${redirectURL}`;
    console.log(authURL);

    var authResult = await browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        interactive: true,
        url: authURL
    });

    // do something with authResult
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply! And thanks for the multiple options + info, alw ays good to know!
Sadly, it didn't seem to do the trick. Could be a webextension thing (since the browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() opens a new window), but for some reason, none of these solutions work. I always put a test after await / inside the foo.then (console.log("test")), but there is no console output. Any ideas?

Comment: Check for errors in console, but use Ctrl+J to open the **browser** console, so you see errors from extensions as well.

Comment: @trincot All I got was:
    unreachable code after return statement  in   btgallery.js:1:52329 (not mine, as far as I know)

    ReferenceError: event is not defined   pop.js:4:6264 (not mine either, as far as I know)

Nothing of my own application, sadly

Comment: @trincot apologies, was on Debug console, not browser console. In this, I found an error, saying that:
    {RedirectURL} uses an invalid safetycerificate. This certificate is only valid for the following names: *.allizom.org, allizom.org <a id="errorCode" title="SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN">SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN</a>"

(translation from native language, apologies if there's a mistake)

Comment: That changes the question quite a bit. I wonder if you should not open a new question about this error condition, because it has nothing to do with promises and how to wait for them.

Comment: @trincot Fair enough. Thanks for helping my find the problem!

Comment: Graag gedaan. Hope you find the solution for that error.